# PySide application lost icons when upgraded to Ubuntu 13.04

Tags: 13.04, qt, pyside

I'm developing an application in Python 3 using PySide. I upgraded my system form 12.10 to 13.04 today, and now I no longer have icons in my toolbar. The icons are loaded using `QIcon.fromTheme()`. Does anybody know why it no longer works? Is there a way to fix this?

Comment: In fact, icons are there if I call `QtGui.QIcon.setThemeName()` with `Humanity`, `ubuntu-mono-light`, or `unity-icon-theme`. But it doesn't work with `gnome` (which is what I get when I call `QtGui.QIcon.themeName()`). However, there is a `/usr/share/icons/gnome` directory with `index.theme` file.